# How do i check product page template in shopify

Tags: shopify

I need to add some text in product page add to cart button, how to check that its product page template.
i have already tried like :: {% if template contains 'product' %}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with

```
{{ template }}
```

Returns `product` if your on a product page. Returns `product.alternate` if that's the template for a specific product